# Is the Windows Forms AcceptButton behavior in effect when the referenced button is disabled?

Tags: .net, winforms, acceptbutton

With the following:

```
this.AcceptButton = this.OKButton;
this.OKButton.Enabled = false;
```

... will the OK button click handler still be invoked when the user presses Enter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it won't be invoked.

Answer (score 3):

No, when the button is disabled, it will not activate and trigger that event.

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

AcceptButton/CancelButton just call the button's PerformClick() method... which doesn't run if the control is disabled.